# Comparing two QuerySets in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have two QuerySets in Django:

```
a = [<Character: Character object>, <Character: Character object>, <Character: Character object>]
b = [<Entity: Entity object>, <Entity: Entity object>, <Entity: Entity object>, <Entity: Entity object>, <Entity: Entity object>, <Entity: Entity object>]
```

I'd like to avoid multiple `for` loops to check if `Character.someattr` is identical with `Entity.someattr` and return a list with `Character` objects, so what would be the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to filter queryset. This way may contain additional query, but it must be much faster, especially with large data.

```
attrs_list = Entity.objects.filter(**filters).distinct().values_list('someattr', flat=True)
a = Character.objects.filter(someotherattr__in=attrs_list)
```

Comment: Or in this case: `b.filter(...)`

Comment: Ok, great, `a` will be perfectly enough for me in my case :) Thanks!

Comment: @errata Glad that I could help :)